# Is there a term for all of your parents' children?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

In other words, is there a collective term for describing your siblings and yourself?

Comment: Isn't it 'children'?

Comment: I'm looking for something that would be in relation to one's self, ie a single word to use in place of "my siblings and I."

Comment: Is there such a word in your native language? If so, what is it? and is there one for 'siblings'? and one for 'children'? How do they all compare?

Comment: There realky isn’t.  In different registers there’s: “My siblings and I” (formal), “All the kids in my family” (informal),   “Me and my brothers and sisters” (colloquial),  “Me and my siblings” (colloquial trying to be formal) “All us kids” (colloquial)...

Comment: This question cannot be answered in abstract if some of their parents' children are not the children of both parents.  In some happy families everyone is happy to call their step-siblings 'brother' of 'sister' without any qualification. In that case the answer to the question is 'My siblings'. But sometimes, regrettably, a child might feel unable to claim any closer relationship than, say,   'My stepmother's children', and that term could be uttered with an intonation full of meaning.

Comment: ‘Siblings’ seems so awkward so, to answer your question, No there isn’t. English is a wretched poor language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase **sibling group** is sometimes used for this: eg

> "being the youngest of my sibling group of five" — Through My Eyes...

or

> "there were seven boys of my sibling group who served in various military units during World War II" — A Year in the Life of a Cowboy

However, it is also used to refer to a group of siblings that you are not necessarily a part of (eg one you have adopted).

The most common way to describe this is certainly to say **"my siblings and I"** or, informally, **"me and my brothers and sisters"**.

Answer (score 1):

You might describe them as a *brood*, but it often has negative connotations.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brood

Answer (score 1):

**“Offspring”**: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offspring

>
off·​spring | \ ˈȯf-ˌspriŋ  \

the product of the reproductive processes of an animal or plant : YOUNG, PROGENY

CHILD
a mother of numerous offspring

Synonyms: fruit, get, issue, posterity, progeny, seed, spawn

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct term is either "my siblings and I" for the nominative case or "my siblings and me" for the objective case. The nominative case is where you would use "we", whereas the objective case is where you would use "us". There are also corresponding terms for the possessive case(s). It is not a case of formal or informal usage, but rather correct usage depending on the structure of the sentence in which the term is to be used.

See for example Composition and Grammar for Public Schools, Ontario Minister of Education, (1920).

Comment: Welcoem to ELU. Please don't direct people to examples: quote them here, *and* link to them if possible.

Comment: Hello, Skelta. Please don't add simplistic workarounds; ELU is aimed at linguists.  Although there is another tag besides 'single word requests', the spirit of the question is clear. Here, the answer seems to be 'There is no specific term; one has to spell it out'.